# Is it possible to have a "case ... of" statement on a tag of a custom type?

Tags: elm

I would like to write a function that encodes a custom type `Decision a` into JSON. The `a` tag could be e.g. `Accept` or `Reject`, and I would like my function to call other functions depending on the type of the tag.

I have tried writing the `case ... of` statement both in terms of the `Decision` type as well as the tag, but have not been able to get either approach to work.

Here are my types:

```
type Decision a
    = Decision Metadata a


type Accepted
    = Accepted AcceptDetails


type Rejected
    = Rejected RejectDetails


type alias Metadata =
    { time : Time.Posix }


type alias AcceptDetails =
    { comment : String }


type alias RejectDetails =
    { reasonCode : Int }
```

Now I would like to write an encoder that can take either type of decision. Something along the lines of:

```
encoder : Decision a -> Json.Encode.Value
encoder decision =
    case decision of
        Decision _ (Accepted _) ->
            acceptedEncoder decision

        Decision _ (Rejected _) ->
            rejectedEncoder decision
```

This does not work but hopefully it conveys what I want - to route the encoding task to the appropriate function.

Is this possible? Or do I have to solve it another way, e.g. by directly calling the right encoder depending on the kind of decision?

I suppose there is a catch in the fact that `a` could be *anything*, but, perhaps naively, that could be handled by adding a `_` case as well.

The compiler gives the error message:

```
The first pattern is trying to match `Decision` values of type:

    Decision Accepted

But the expression between `case` and `of` is:

    Decision a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `a` in `Decision a` is only ever going to be either an `Approved` or `Rejected` type, it seems that merging the two constructors into a single type would be appropriate.

```
type DecisionResult
    = Accepted AcceptDetails
    | Rejected RejectDetails
```

This would remove the need for the type parameter on `Decision`:

```
type Decision
    = Decision Metadata DecisionResult
```

Your `encoder` function could then route the decision metadata and approved/rejected details to the more specific encoders:

```
encoder : Decision -> Json.Encode.Value
encoder (Decision meta result) =
    case result of
        Accepted details ->
            acceptedEncoder meta details

        Rejected details ->
            rejectedEncoder meta details

acceptedEncoder : Metadata -> AcceptDetails -> Json.Encode.Value
acceptedEncoder meta details =
    ...

rejectedEncoder : Metadata -> RejectDetails -> Json.Encode.Value
rejectedEncoder meta details =
    ...
```

Comment: Even if it isn't the only two constructors, you could parameterize `DecisionResult` instead and add an `Other a` constructor.

Comment: It seems to me that with this solution both `acceptedEncoder` and `rejectedEncoder` would now have to handle both types of decisions with their own `case decision of` statements. More generally, I lose the ability to write functions that only accept one of the types of `Decisions`. Is there another way to avoid that downside?

Comment: Good point @ErikEng. I've updated the answer with a refined `encoder` function and new signatures for `acceptedEncoder` and `rejectedEncoder`

Comment: Thanks! This works for my use case. But I am still wondering if it's possible to accomplish something similar without changing the `Decision` type. From a learning point of view I think it could also be helpful to understand why this is not possible, if that is the case.

Comment: Elm is statically typed and the compiler needs to know the type in advance, and pattern matching only works on constructors. If Elm had typeclasses like Haskell, you would have more flexibility. But for the case you've outlined, refactoring the `Decision` type seems like the best way to go.